# bootstrap collapse: change display of toggle button icons and text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to create collapsible sections of text. The sections are expanded when a + button is pressed. My html code as follows:

**[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/baishi/bE3Bw/1/)**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Open
        </button>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Contents:Thank you to help me solve the problem, you're a great guy!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Later, i need to change text, button icons and expand.**

Is Open:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Close
</button>
```

Is Close:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Open
</button>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

based on:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16870379/1596547

```
$('button span').parent().click(function () {
if($('button span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'))
{
   $('button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Close'); 
}
else
{      
    $('button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Open'); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 51):

It is also possible to do by css styles.

in css add style:

```
.text-toogle[aria-expanded=false] .text-expanded {
  display: none;
}
.text-toogle[aria-expanded=true] .text-collapsed {
  display: none;
}
```

and use in html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default text-toogle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tabsNavigation" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="text-collapsed">More info</span>
    <span class="text-expanded">Less info</span>

    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

---

Please remember to add attribute

```
aria-expanded="false"
```

and class

```
text-toogle
```

to link / button.

Comment: This worked for me, however I was thrown off by the odd spelling of "toggle".  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Toogle

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery then make use of `toggleClass`

```
$('div.toggler').click(function(){
  $('div.toggler span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prathviraj080/vbbbw46a/1/) here

Answer (score 0):

I found this question and answer helpful. I removed the parent() method and added an id to my + button to avoid changing other buttons when toggling +.

```
$('#more').click(function () {
if($('button span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'))
{
    $('#more').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Less Info'); 
}
else
{      
    $('#more').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> More Info'); 
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maybolles/opbyvbv4/2/

Answer (score -1):

use this javascript for changing icon

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demo").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
        $(".btn").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Open');
    });
    $("#demo").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
        $(".btn").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Close');
    });
    $("#demo1").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
        $(".btn1").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Open');
    });
    $("#demo1").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
        $(".btn1").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Close');
    });
});
```

Comment: Downvoting as this is a lot of unnecessary DOM work that could just as easily be replaced with a simple toggleClass which itself could be done in CSS and using native bootstrap functionality.