# Bootstrap 3 - Change Glyphicon in Panel-Title based on Accordion Collapsed State

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and am building an accordion that will house a lot of filters. Users will be able to toggle the filters open and closed and I'd like to add to glyphion to the panel-title that visually reinforces the state of the panel.

It feels like this should be a pretty basic thing to do within Bootstrap (and I'd really like to use as vanilla of Bootstrap functionality as possible), but I can't find anything in the GetBootstrap.com documentation that addresses this.

Here's a snippet of my markup. I've removed everything I tried that didn't work.

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h5>narrow by:</h5>

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

            <!-- CATEGORY
            ================================================== -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseCategory">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></i> category
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div> <!-- panel-heading -->

                <div id="collapseCategory" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>[workflow]</p>
                    </div> <!-- panel-body -->
                </div> <!-- panel-collapse -->
            </div> <!-- panel -->

        </div> <!-- panel-group -->

    </div> <!-- col -->


    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h5>search results</h5>
    </div> <!-- col -->

</div> <!-- row -->
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the code shown below after Bootstrap's javascript on document ready:

```
$('#collapseCategory').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
$('a.accordion-toggle > i').removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-up').addClass('glyphicon-collapse-down');
});  
$('#collapseCategory').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
$('a.accordion-toggle > i').removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-down').addClass('glyphicon-collapse-up');
});
```

Also see: [bootstrap collapse: change display of toggle button icons and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050972/bootstrap-collapse-change-display-of-toggle-button-icons-and-text/19053709)