# How do I use jquery for multiple buttons that collapse multiple sections without writing code for each section?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used this example: [bootstrap collapse: change display of toggle button icons and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050972/bootstrap-collapse-change-display-of-toggle-button-icons-and-text)

Had to put the data-toggle and data-target in each button to get the text and the glyphicon to collapse the section. Otherwise the glyphicon just changes the button.

Here is the collapse code (I have 8 of these on the page):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<h2>English</h2>              
<p class="collapse" id="en-one">This handbook explains your rights and responsibilities when you apply
                            for and claim unemployment benefits. Read it, and, if you don't understand
                            it or have questions, call the claims center at 800-318-6022 for help.
                            Free interpretive services are available to answer your questions if you
                            don't speak English. You are responsible for understanding this information.
                            You may be denied benefits if you don't follow the instructions in this
                            handbook. If you knowingly break the rules, you could be denied benefits
                            for committing fraud, which may lead to serious consequences, including
                            civil and criminal penalties. Keep this handbook for future reference. </p>                                     
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#en-one">
                         View details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#en-one"></span>
</button>
</div><!--/span-->
</div><!--/row-->
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$('button span').parent().click(function () {
if($('button span').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'))
{
$('button').html('Hide details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#en-one"></span>'); 
}
else
{      
 $('button').html('View details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#en-one"></span>'); 
}
});
```

Comment: Would jQueryUI accordion help? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xDhS2

```
<p class="collapse">This handbook explains ....</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="btn-text">View details</span> 
    <span class="btn-text hide">Hide details</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
</button>
```

---

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).prev('p').collapse('toggle');
    $(this).find('span.btn-text').toggleClass('hide');
    $(this).find('span.glyphicon')
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down');
});
```

Notice that I've removed IDs and data attributes from your HTML as they're not needed. Also, it would be wise to put a class on the toggle buttons and target those so you aren't seeing oddness with other buttons on the page:

```
$('button.my-class').click(...
```

Comment: Oops. I squelched your button text toggling. Stand by.

Comment: Updated to fix button text.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/y3y3x/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('p').toggle();
});
```

I also added one that slides the content up/down.

EDIT: here is an updated fiddle that changes the button text - http://jsfiddle.net/y3y3x/2/

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('p').toggle();
    var currentText = $.trim($(this).text());
    if('Hide details' == currentText) {
        $(this).text('View details');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Hide details');
    }
});
```

Comment: That works well but the business unit wants the button to change to hide details when the accordion is expanded.

Comment: Ah, yes - it was an example to see if we were headed in the right direction. The answer above covers all of your needs.