# How can I change color based on element collapse status?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to set different colors depending on whether the div is collapsed or expanded.

For example: If some section is collapsed, I want to set the background color of my button and header color `<h2>` to be more muted (to be specific `rgb(115, 129, 184);`), and when the same section is expanded I want them to be set to my primary color (`rgb(54, 74, 153);`).

Here's my HTML file:

```html
<section id="category">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
    <h2>Category</h2>
      <button class="btn section-dropdown-btn float-right" type="button" 
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#categoryitems" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="dropdown-expanded fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        <i class="dropdown-collapsed fa fa-angle-up"></i>
      </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

And my CSS ([based on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291535): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291535):

```css
.section-dropdown-btn[aria-expanded=false] .dropdown-collapsed{
    display: none;
}

.section-dropdown-btn[aria-expanded=true] .dropdown-expanded{
    display: none;
}

.section-dropdown-btn[aria-expanded=false]{
    background-color: rgb(115, 129, 184);
}

.section-dropdown-btn[aria-expanded=true]{
    background-color: rgb(54, 74, 153);
}
```

But I don't feel like this is a great and clean solution. Also, only button has that `aria-expanded` attribute, so my `<h2>` tag can't easily determine if it's collapsed or not. I would also have to make many similar CSS rules, about one class just to change one attribute.

How can I achieve that and how could I avoid repetitiveness?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap puts `collapse` and `show` classes on the element when it does its thing. You should be able to target those with your CSS selectors. That doesn't help with your parent element problem, but it's cleaner than using the ARIA attribute.

For the parent selector you can use the available [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#events). Write a function something like this, with a similar inverse function for hide:

```
$('.item-wrapper').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).closest('h2').addClass('blah');
});
```

Then you'd use your custom class for all CSS inside that element.